# Staged, unstaged, unpushed and unpulled. Correct workflow?

Tags: git

In my local repository I have commits that are not on the remote (**unpushed**). In the remote repository I also have commits that are not on local (**unpulled**). On top of that, I have both **staged** and **unstaged** changes on a couple of files.

*What is the recommended workflow to keep things sane and avoid having to --force to the remote? Should I stash my changes, reset the repo, stash again, pull and then apply stash?*

I'm not so experienced with git workflows, but I assume this must be something that happens quite often. I'll accept being forwarded to other questions that solve my problem, but I couldn't find any, or didn't know how to search for it properly.

Comment: Why do you need to force push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to pull the remote commits to update the local branch and at the same time keep the staged and unstaged changes. If so, I would recommend:

```
git stash
git pull origin -r <branch>
git stash apply
```

I prefer `git pull -r` than `git pull` in most cases in order to avoid unnecessary merge commits. `git pull -r` is equivalent to `git fetch && git rebase` while `git pull` is `git fetch && git merge`.

And I favour `git stash apply` over `git stash pop`, because `pop` removes the last stashed state while I want to keep it in case I'll need it again.

Answer (score 1):

I normally do temporary commit and then take a pull from the remote. Following are the steps:

```
git add .
git commit -m"<commit message>"
git pull --rebase
```

Now, you have latest from remote and your local changes are also there. 
You can decide what to do with temporary commit, you want to push it or keep on working on it. If you don't want to push the temporary commit, just 
do `git reset HEAD~1` and push the other local changes.

Now your local and remote are in sync and your staging area have your un-committed changes.